# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Requested the number of rows for section (0) which is out of bounds.'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm getting this error when I try to run my app on iOS 13, older versions was working fine.

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Requested the number of rows for section (0) which is out of bounds.'
```

This is what I presume that is causing the exception

```
override func reloadData() {
    super.reloadData()

    let rows = self.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) // what I know is that this line is causing the exception
    if (rows > 0) {
        if placeholderStackView != nil {
            self.placeholderStackView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    } else {
        setTableStatus(type: .empty)
    }

}
```

when I set the variable row to a number it loads without exception, I presume that an update on UITableView SDK caused it, I've tried searching google for some insights, but no success on this.

Comment: What is the result if you log `self.numberOfSections`?

Comment: It doesn't have a result it launches the exception.

Comment: `self.numberOfSections` cannot launch the above exception as it doesn't look at rows. I posted an answer.

Comment: real quick, is this a table?

Comment: @jbiser361 yes is a table

Comment: Alright, well you really don’t need need the number of sections unless you plan on having more than 1 because Xcode already assumes you’ll have one section. Does that make sense?

Comment: I didn't understand, I'm not an iOS Developer just trying to figure out some bugs that are ocurring in the new versions of iOS (13)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check for `self.numberOfSections` first. If there are no sections, then there can be no rows in that section (out of bounds).

```
override func reloadData() {
    super.reloadData()

    guard 0 < self.numberOfSections && 0 < self.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) else {
        setTableStatus(type: .empty)
        return
    }

    if placeholderStackView != nil {
        self.placeholderStackView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: You did not have any sections. Therefore the app will crash because you are asking the number of rows for a section that does not exist. Think of it as getting the 10th element in an array that only has 5 elements.

Comment: So out of bounds means doesn't exist?

Comment: Doesn't exist would mean it is `nil`. However, the array in question (`numberOfSections` is an array) is strong, not weak. Which means it will always exist (even if it is empty). This is a very important distinction in coding that you will need to understand to resolve various bugs in the future.

Comment: Out of bounds means you are giving an instruction to access an element at an index where there is no element. I see you up voted my answer. Please click the checkmark to indicate it is a working answer so others who come across this page with this issue can see it is a working answer.