# NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Requested the number of rows for section (0) which is out of bounds

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

In iOS 13 getting exception, it work perfect for iOS12.

Exception : {Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Requested the number of rows for section (0) which is out of bounds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Requested the number of rows for section (0) which is out of bounds.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61141561/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-reason-requested-the-number-of-rows-for-se)

Comment: @dazzieta I need this in Xamarin

Comment: It would be better to post the relevant code , which will be helpful to solve the error .